# New navigation causes homepage to freeze on Chrome for iOS

Tags: bug, status-deferred, new-nav, google-chrome

The latest iteration of the navigation has left the homepage on (M)SO to freeze Chrome 44.0.2403.67 (for iOS) for a good ~5 seconds.

This isn't a one off, nor am I exaggerating the 5 seconds. This happens *every page load* on both my iPad and iPhone (both iOS 8.4) and lasts... for ~5 seconds.

Repo URL's:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/jquery?show=all&sort=recentlyactive (the `jquery` tag here is just an example; any tag page yields this behaviour).

If I AJAX navigate to one of the other tabs ("popular", "needs answer") and then AJAX navigate *back* to "new", the freeze does not occur. The freeze *only* occurs on a normal HTTP request/ refresh.

Whilst frozen, I often see half a loading spinner in the (horizontal) centre of the question nav items (see images below). I also *very often* see the order of the questions change once the page unfreezes (again, see images below).

1. Whilst frozen:

   [image]
2. Unfrozen:

   [image]

Answer (score 4):

The new **alpha** nav UI has not yet been optimized for mobile, and indeed is not officially supported  on mobile. I suspect you had to click "full site" for it even to load (it 404s by default, although I might rip  that out). When we write a mobile skin for the new nav UI, it will be appropriately tested. For now: I think the best advice would be "don't use the new nav UI using a mobile device by forcing it to use the full-site UI".